# Pick block doesnt work creative mc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So In creative ik that I Can pick up blocks with the middle scroll button on my mouse, but it doesn't work anymore somehow and My settings are on middle at consoles etc. So idk what to do because when I play now it is so annoying that I need to search up every block I want to use

Answer (score 1):

Check that the bind for pick block actually is middle click. Forgive me if I misunderstood, but I take it that you set the bind to middle click on console. You need to set it to middle click on PC, not console. You must have changed the bind at some point since middle click is the default bind to pick block.